# Custom Field Not Showing Up for Opportunity Product

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem, product, product2

I would like my sales team to see a custom field — Unit of Measurement (UOM), which is a pick list — for each product when they’re adding it to an opportunity. I have added the UOM field to the Product Opp object by using a formula. I have also added the field to the Page Layout and the Mini-Page Layout.

However, I’m still not seeing this field show up when I add a product to my opportunities. I can’t figure it out.

Can someone please suggest how I should do this?

Comment: Check the FLS permissions for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If this were not a formula field, you would need to add the field to the [multi-line layout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.layouts_opp_product_multiline.htm&type=5). At the top of the page layout editor for your opportunity product, click Edit Multi-Line Layout.

Unfortunately, it looks like you can't add formula fields to the multi-line layout. [Go vote for the idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVzjUAF/opportunity-product-multiline-layout)!

Comment: The field isn't listed as an option for multi-line layout. Any idea how I add it there?

Comment: I missed that it was a formula field. You can't add formula fields to the multi-line layout. I'll update my answer.